# How to use a dynamic array with `PropTypes.oneOf`?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Since `oneOf` [only accepts array](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/9057907/factoryWithTypeCheckers.js#L277), I decided to define a checker function and written the following code, however, it does not work.

```
const mapping = {
  foo: ["aaa", "bbb"],
  bar: ["ccc", "ddd"]
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  variant: (props, propName, componentName) => {
    if(props[propName]) PropTypes.oneOf(mapping[props.type])
  },
  tag: PropTypes.string
};
```

What is the right way to use another built-in checker function in a custom checker function? Is it possible?